# What does this 'it' indicate?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Harry!" Neville burst out, the moment he saw the other two. "I was
>   trying to find you to warn you, I heard Malfoy saying he was going to
>   catch you, he said you had a drag ––" 
>       Harry shook his head violently to shut Neville up, but Professor McGonagall had seen. She looked more likely to breathe fire than
>   Norbert as she towered over the three of them. 
>       "I would never have believed **it** of any of you. Mr. Filch says you were up in the astronomy tower. It's one o'clock in the morning.
>   Explain yourselves."  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What does ‘it’ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prof. McGonagall supplies specific referents in her next sentences: their being up in the astronomy tower and their being out of bed at one o'clock in the morning.

But really this *it* refers to the entire situation. What McGonagall finds unexpected is the students' misconduct.